# Is my modal not showing because of z-index?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating an app-look-a-like mobile version of my site.  In the bottom, there is a menu icon that should trigger a modal when clicked, however this is not happening, the modal is not showing.  I'm not sure if this is happening because of the z-index. If so, is there a way I can solve this using only CSS? I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/MWeZVmp)

```css
.footer-container-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #8ABE57;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.footer-container-mobile i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.circle-btn-mobile {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #31353C;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.circle-btn-mobile-container {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  z-index: 50;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex footer-container-mobile dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="mr-auto" data-toggle="modal" id="modalServiceMenuMobile"><i class="far fa-bars">Menu icon</i></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="ml-auto"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>Icon</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row circle-btn-mobile-container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto circle-btn-mobile">
      <i class="far fa-plus">+</i>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalServiceMenuMobile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalServiceMenuMobile" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The codepen URL is empty?

Comment: Like was pointed out your codepen example is empty, and I only see the bootstrap css which won't invoke the modal without also having the bootstrap javascript files. So without seeing a full example first guess would be you're missing the bootstrap js files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle click event using CSS/HTML. Alternatively, you may use `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active` pseudo-classes using CSS. You may find more pseudo-classes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). I highly recommend to use JS in your situation in order to have better control on HTML elements. You may check the JS click event example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

Answer (score 0):

I made a rookie mistake.

I forgot to add the `data-target="#idHere"` to my `<a href="#">`
By adding this, I solved my issue.  Thanks for the help anyways, made me realize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have 2 elements that have the same ID, which is a problem:

```
<a href="#" class="mr-auto" data-toggle="modal" id="modalServiceMenuMobile"><i class="far fa-bars">Menu icon</i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalServiceMenuMobile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalServiceMenuMobile" aria-hidden="true">
```

What you need to do is:

1. Give the `div` that's gonna be your modal a unique ID different from the link that's trying to open it.
2. Give the `a` element calling the modal the data attribute `data-target="#[name_of_modal_id]"`. It's important that you have the `#` symbol before the modal ID you're trying to reference. Example: `data-target="#modalDiv"`.